# Style UIPageViewController page space

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

What is the best way to add a style (an image for example) between pages of a `UIPageViewController`? The calendar app kind of does this (not sure if that's using `UIPageViewController` or not):

[image].

The only thing I can think of doing is to hang a UIView off the side of the page (view controller). This seems to work, but feels dirty.